# What's the right way to have a contextual link on controller action?

Tags: 8, navigation

I just installed a custom module and created a controller with index function in it. I want to have a contextual link for this. I have following code in index function.

```
public function index() {
    return [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Implement method: hello'),
        '#contextual_links' => [
            'mymodule' => 'mymodule.another_action',
        ],
    ];
}
```

File : mymodule.links.contextual.yml

```
mymodule_configure:
  title: 'Configure Custom Module'
  route_name: 'mymodule.another_action'
  group: 'my_module'
```

Please suggest the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using a reference from below.

[Adding the contextual link render element](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217608/adding-the-contextual-link-render-element)

I added a variable to the theme, and passed contextual link in controller function to twig template using that variable. Please see code below.

File : mymodule.module

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'mymodule' => [
      'template' => 'mymodule',
      'variables' => [              //Added a variable content
        'content' => '',
      ]
    ],
  ];
}
```

File : mymodule.links.contextual.yml

```
mymodule_configure:
  title: 'Configure My Module'
  route_name: 'mymodule.route_name'
  group: 'mymodule'
```

File : IndexController.php

```
public function index() {
    $data['content'] = [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Implement method: index'),
    ];

    $data['#contextual_links'] = [
        'mymodule' => [
            'route_parameters' => [],
        ],
    ];

    return [
        '#theme' => 'mymodule',
        '#content' => $data,        //Pass Contextual link to the variable
    ];
}
```

File : mymodule.html.twig

```
{%
set classes = [
'contextual-region'
]
%}

<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {{ content }}                     //Render here
</div>
```

--

Thanks